# What does it mean "bytes numbered from 0 (LSB) to 3 (MSB)"?

Tags: c, byte

I should extract byte `n` from word `x`.
Example: `getByte(0x12345678,1) = 0x56`.
And there is written, that bytes numbered from 0(LSB) to 3(MSB), the meaning of which I can't understand.
Thank you.

Comment: LSB=Least significant byte (or bit), MSB=Most significant byte (or bit). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_significant_bit for an explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you are supposed to consider *x* composed of bytes as *x* = ∑<sub>*n*∈[0,4)</sub> *b*<sub>n</sub> × 256<sup>*n*</sup>, and given *x* you are supposed to compute *b*<sub>*n*</sub>. That is, *b*<sub>0</sub> is the least-significant byte and *b*<sub>3</sub> is the most-significant byte.

Answer (score 3):

Consider your 32 bit word (`0x12345678`) as 4 bytes:

```
Word  : 12 34 56 78 (hex)
Byte #:  3  2  1  0
        MSB<-----LSB
```

- MSB = Most Significant Byte
- LSB = Least Signficant Byte

Answer (score 0):

MSB and LSB mean Most Significative Byte and Least Significative Byte, respectively. A byte being a 8-bit number that can be directly represented by 2 hexadecimal positions. So, the number 0x12345678 is a word containing 4 bytes, 12 34 56 78. The rightmost is the LSB, and the leftmost is the MSB. So you are taking the byte 1 that is the SECOND byte from right to left.